# storybook: Using argtypes in mdx does not have control

Tags: reactjs, controls, storybook, mdxjs

**I edit my storybook with .mdx, but something wrong!**

My code is as follows：

```
<!---Badge.stories.mdx --->

import { Meta, Story, Canvas, ArgsTable } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';
import Badge from '../components/Badge';

<Meta
    title="MDX/Badge"
    component={Badge}
    argTypes={{
        size: {
            name: 'size',
            description: 'Badge Size ',
            options: ['large', 'small'],
            control: {type: 'radio'},
            table: {
                type: {summary: 'string'},
                defaultValue: { summary: 'large' }
            }
        }
    }}
/>

export const Template = (args) => <Badge {...args } >信息</Badge>

# Badge

<Canvas>
  <Story name="Example" args={{
    size: 'large',
    dot: false,
    text: '5',
    overflowCount: '99'
  }}>
    {Template.bind({})}
  </Story>
</Canvas>


### API
<ArgsTable of={Badge} />
```

I can't see control in storybook.

[image]
But if I write my story in `**.stories.js`  ,anything is ok!

[image]

Can somebody help me ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the `story` prop instead of `of` with the name of the story.

```
<Canvas withSource="open">
  <Story name="Basic usage">{Template.bind({})}</Story>
</Canvas>


<ArgsTable story="Basic usage" />
```

Comment: I tried.

From the official documents, it seems that `.mdx` does not support  `control`.

https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-docs/mdx#customizing-argtypes-with-mdx.

Comment: That's weird because in our projects we are using this approach and it's working. 
In this link, I can't see an example with prop `story` instead of `of` prop.

Comment: Really？Do I need to configure some addons?